# jQuery Ajax Mail not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am not a pro and I am sorry.

I have a problem with my client script which is on a wordpress.
Here is the [link](http://thefarmantiques.com/garden-accessories/) to the website,if you click any image it will open in a lightbox and you can see the inputs down.

It was made by someone long ago.

The script should s**end the data to the email you write** in the input,but it's just **not working**.I get alert saying "message cant be sent".

Here is the jQuery code.Thank You.
And here you can see the [/email_client.php](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/09e01b574d1eda42384b27969ba1a370)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    if(jQuery('#mbCenter').length > 0) {
        var toinject = '<div class="print-no">\
                            <span id="flo_customprintwrap">\
                                <a href="#" onclick="printthisonly()">Print</a>\
                                <em>||</em>\
                                <a href="#" onclick="jQuery(\'#flo_mailform\').slideToggle(); return false;">E-mail</a>\
                            </span>\
                            <div id="flo_mailform">\
                                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="E-mail address" >\
                                <input type="submit" onclick="mailme();" value="Send" >\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    ';
        jQuery('#mbCloseLink').before(toinject);
    }
});
function printthisonly() {
    /*jQuery('#top').addClass('print-no');
    jQuery('#content').addClass('print-no');
    jQuery('#footer').addClass('print-no');*/
    jQuery('#outer-wrapper-wide').addClass('print-no');
    jQuery('#mbCenter').addClass('print-only');
    jQuery('#mbTitle').addClass('pf-title');
    jQuery('#mbCenter').css('margin-top', 0);
    jQuery('#mbCenter').css('margin-left', 0);
    window.print();
};
function mailme() {
jQuery('#mbMedia img').css('max-width', '100%');
var content_mail = [];
var content_mail = [ jQuery('#mbMedia').html(), jQuery('#mbTitle').html(), jQuery('#mbSbtitle').html(), jQuery('#mbCaption').html(), jQuery('#flo_mailform input[type="text"]').val() ];
jQuery.ajax({        
       type: "POST",
       url: "/email_client.php",
       data: { content : content_mail },
       success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
       }
    }); 
return false;
}
```

Comment: If you are getting it in an alert from this piece of code, then it's surely the data you are getting back from the email_client.php file. Please post the response code of file for more reference.

Comment: @Ali i had found it , im thinking how can i show it here , there was that demo site where i can put code in it https://gist.github.com/anonymous/09e01b574d1eda42384b27969ba1a370

Comment: you probably need to check the error in sending the mail, I checked the link you shared. Try uncommenting the ` //echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;` to get the error info

Comment: @Ali I manage to do something , i changed host and password.Now from what i read in google , i have problem with SSL .
i get this error : warning stream_socket_enable_crypto() ssl operation failed with code 1

Comment: I changed this code from tsl to SSL . and i get the same warning , message can not be sent.

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'

Comment: @Ali Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. so yes its SMTP problem , i uncommented that echo

Comment: Try changing the app/config/email.php
smtp to mail

Comment: @Ali I fixed it , i had to comment this line   //$mail->isSMTP(); Thank you for ur help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151004/discussion-between-ali-and-agnes-pandek).